# tmux and multiple PuTTY/KiTTY sessions

Tags: putty, tmux

I recently swapped from `screen` to `tmux`.

I have two physical screens, and I used to open two PuTTY sessions to a unique SSH server.
This two sessions are attached to the same `tmux` instance.

The problem is when I change the current window on the first PuTTY, the second PuTTY is also changed.

Do you know how to have two different visualizations for a single `tmux` instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [wemux](https://github.com/zolrath/wemux).

This allows you to join a tmux session in three different modes:

1. Mirror (read-only access for other clients)
2. Pair (all clients see the same thing, and have write access)
3. Rogue (clients are independent)

It sounds like you want rogue mode. Bear in mind that if two clients are viewing the same tmux window, the screen size will be that of the smallest attached client.